# jQuery check if a class exists

Tags: jquery

So, I have a js which gets the class when a button is clicked:

```
var rhp_class = jQuery(this).attr("class");
```

Let say one button shows the following classes: `name address phone`

How do I check if the variable contains a class `address` ?

I tried something like this:

```
if( rhp_class.hasClass( "address" )) {      
        alert("It does ");
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your variable:

```
var rhp_class = jQuery(this);
```

The issue is you are trying to look for a class in a string value while `.hasClass()` needs to be bind on jQuery object. So in your case it is `$(this)`.

Comment: Yeah, I was making things too complicated. I decided to go with your advice. Thanks! =)

Comment: @steveKim you are welcome and such things happens when you're really busy in thinking. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks and i totally agree! haha

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.hasClass()` over jquery object of element and not on class value in string form:

```
if(jQuery(this).hasClass("address")) {      
    alert("It does ");
};
```

Comment: How about checking if a string exists in the variable?

Comment: @steveKim: you will need to split(.split(/\s+/)) return classes by space to get all class array in it and then use indexof method to find occurence in it. however , that is not a good way for comparison.

Comment: I see. So, things might get a bit complicated. Alright, thanks for the help thought! =)